# Play Store-Android App needs Specific Files for Specific device attached

Tags: android, google-play

I developed one app for android. I need to release this app on `Google Store`. That app actually connects one device with android device and do specific tasks. The attached device needs calibration files for working perfectly. Every device has different calibration files, so this means for every user, I need to supply files separately. I have the idea that I will upload the files on `server` and as the user will connect the device for the first time to the android device, a connection will be established to the server and specific files for that specific attached device will be downloaded. This will be done only for the first time and files will be saved in the app.

Questions:
1) My method is applicable?
2) Any other method to implement this?
3) which online storage is best candidate for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is applicable. Host the set of files on a server and download it to phone's storage with the specified url of the set of files.

Google play uploading is a different scenario, it does not concern about the files that are hosted in servers.